# Why doesn't XElement have a GetAttributeValue method?

Tags: c#, linq, xelement, system.xml

Sometimes I'd like to know the reasoning of certain API changes. Since Google hasn't helped me with this question, maybe StackOverflow can. Why did Microsoft choose to remove the `GetAttribute` helper method on XML elements? In the `System.Xml` world there was `XmlElement.GetAttribute("x")` like `getAttribute` in MSXML before it, both of which return either the attribute value or an empty string when missing. With `XElement` there's `SetAttributeValue` but `GetAttributeValue` wasn't implemented.

Certainly it's not too much work to modify logic to test and use the `XElement.Attribute("x").Value` property but it's not as convenient and providing the utility function one way (`SetAttributeValue`) but not the other seems weird. Does anyone out there know the reasons behind the decision so that I can rest easily and maybe learn something from it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are supposed to get attribute value like this:

```
var value = (TYPE) element.Attribute("x");
```

**UPDATE:**

Examples:

```
var value = (string) element.Attribute("x");
var value = (int) element.Attribute("x");
```

etc.

See this article: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ImprovingLINQCodeSmellWithExplicitAndImplicitConversionOperators.aspx. Same thing works for attributes.

Comment: That returns an instance of XAttribute.  No idea how casting it to System.Type is going to be helpful.

Comment: Not to System.Type lol, whatever type you need it to be. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Nice, didn't know about the type conversion on those classes.  Thanks!

Comment: I just commented on this topic here (http://mo.notono.us/2010/08/xelement-xattribute-and-explicit.html), but I'm stuck with the thought that the explicit type conversion operators are a bad thing.  There is no intellisense for them, and they look like just a garden variety cast. - Kirk's confusion is perfectly understandable.

Even though the conversion operators exist, I think I will prefer the extension method, if only because it is explicitly obvious what it does...

PS! note that you need to use the nullable type cast if there's a chance the attribute or element does not exist.

Comment: Necros, you've exposed something I was unfamiliar with before this posting. Awesome to learn something new, thanks. It's plausible the GetAttribute method was removed to highlight this mechanism but I still wish I had more insight into the decision. I'm not certain I prefer this route but I've been using it bit and when casting to non-string types it removes some extra steps

Comment: Note that this construct does NOT work when the attribute is not present (unlike the VB.NET "Extension Property" `.Value` which always returns a `String`, but you can then convert it to other types). (I note Oskar has mentioned this issue.)

Comment: SetAttributeValue can write Size and Point types but reading doesn't work: `mainForm.Location = (Point)el.Attribute("Location");  mainForm.Size = (Size)el.Attribute("Size");`

Answer (score 5):

Not sure exactly the reason, but with C# extension methods, you can solve the problem yourself.

```
public static string GetAttributeValue(this XElement element, XName name)
{
    var attribute = element.Attribute(name);
    return attribute != null ? attribute.Value : null;
}
```

Allows:

```
element.GetAttributeValue("myAttributeName");
```

Comment: I often end up doing essentially what this function does and certainly this is the best approach IMO but I'm interested in *why* GetAttribute is missing from the API when it's been there in previous models and they provide a helper for the setter

Comment: @Geograph what do you mean?  XML attribute values are strings at heart.  If you want it as something else, you must convert it yourself.